# Why application size increases after moving to sd card?

Tags: applications, sd-card, app2sd

I installed application and see that it allocates say 35Mb. Then I moved it to alsd card and it allocates 41+Mb. I see these "changes" for every application which is moved to sd card. Why it is happens?

Comment: Some hints may be found in our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info): with the standard App2SD implementation, parts of the app are remaining in device storage. I didn't investigate this deeper, but assume there is some overlap. It might also be that some of the code is extracted (`.apk` files are zipped) which otherwise remains packed. Not knowing exactly, I better leave answering to someone who does :)